# Unintentional infinite 'for' loop

Tags: c

I just started programming in C, and while practicing with for loops, I came up with the following piece of code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main()
    {
        int x;

        for (x=0;x=10;x=x+1)

           printf("%d\n",x);

        return 0;

    }
```

When I run the code, I fall into an infinite loop. In my C manual it says that the condition x =10 is always true, but I can't get my head around it. If I give the variable x a value of 0 at the beginning, should the for loop not even start, or when the value of x reaches 10, shouldn't the loop stop?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `for (x=0;x=10;x=x+1)`-> `for (x=0;x<10;x=x+1)`

Comment: `=` means "assignment" or "initialization" in C, never "comparison".

Comment: or.. `for (x=0;x!=10;x=x+1)`

Comment: Change `=` to `==` so `x==10` (comparison) instead of `x=10` (assignment).

Comment: x=10 mean x is set to 10, and in C language, 10 mean true
So your loop become an infiniti loop

Comment: A good way to stop this from happening is the flip your comparisons so that the literal is first `10==x;`.  You would have typed `10=x;` which would be caught by the compiler

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The condition part of your `for` loop is wrong. What you are doing is :

```
for (x = 0; x = 10; x = x +1) {
    // Operations
}
```

The condition you have got here is `x = 10` which is an affectation. So `x = 10` will return 10, which also means `true`. Your `for` loop is equivalent to :

```
for (x = 0; true; x = x + 1) {
    // Operations
}
```

This is why you have got an infinite loop, you should replace the affectation operator `=` by the comparason one with two equals sign `==`. This means the `for` will loop while `x` is equals to 10.

**EDIT** : As Virgile mentioned in comments, for the second `for` loop, `x` will go from 0 to `INT_MAX`, then the behavior is undefined. So, your code is more likely to look like :

```
for (x = 0; true; x = 10) {
    // Operations
}
```

Comment: Both `for` loop are not equivalent, apart from the fact that they are infinite. In the former, `x` will always be equal to `10`  in the body of the loop, while in the latter it will increase from `0` to `INT_MAX` (after which UB will be triggered).

Answer (score 0):

When entering a `for` loop, the initialization part is performed first.  So after the loop initialization `x` is 0.

Before entering the body of the loop, even the first time, the condition is checked.  The "condition" in this case does not compare `x` to 10 but *sets it to 10* since you are using `=` instead of `==`.

Since an assignment as an expression has the value of the variable after assignment, the conditional expression has a value of 10 since that is what was assigned to `x`.  Because this value is non-zero, it evaluates to true, and always will.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is, you are implicitly converting `int` to `bool` in this line:

```
for (x=0;x=10;x=x+1)
         ^^^^
```

here, `x=10;` results `true`

So, it prints `10` everytime as you are using the `=` assignment operator.

```
for(int x=0;true;x=x+1)
```

What you could do to maintain the loop?

- Use [relational operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Comparison_operators.2Frelational_operators):

  - `for (x=0;x!=10;x=x+1)`
  - `for (x=0;x==10;x=x+1)`
  - `for (x=0;x<10;x=x+1)`

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is, Take a close look on the condition part(2), in this what x=10, means is it is just assigning the value 10 to x, and it returns "True" always, so no problem what you have incrementing, it comes to 10 always, Thus infinite loop.